# How to implement the functionality of ngClass (AngularJS 1.x) in AngularJS 2?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS 1.x, there is the ngClass directive to bind a CSS name dynamically. How to implement the same functionality in AngularJS 2?

Answer (score 4):

Angular 2 has a special syntax that replaces `ng-*`

It actually works in a very similar fashion. To change HTML properties/attributes you just need to use the square brackets syntax.

```
<div [class]="{error: errorCount > 0}"></div>
```

Same goes for style, checked, disabled, etc.

API: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/directives/CSSClass-class.html

Comment: Many thanks. But we failed to pass the example for AngularJS version 2.0.0-alpha.34. The output error message in Chrome is "EXCEPTION: Can't bind to 'class' since it isn't a known property of the '<div>' element and there are no matching directives with a corresponding property".

Comment: I am sorry to say that we failed to import CSSClass. It works now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Would appreciate it if you accepted the answer. Gotta get dat rep up.